# How can i pass my variable values from console application to windows form application

Tags: c#

I am stuck on my project after calculating the data in the console application i needed to pass it to windows form application and then display the values on a bar graph chart.

Comment: Does your Windows Forms application invoke your console application?

Comment: Do you want Run your WinForms application with some arguments, or you want to exchange some data between two started apps?

Comment: both of them are in the same project

Comment: i just want to display my console application data inside the windows form application window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a whole range of options, varying in various forms of transport, complexity, performance & overhead. One of the simple ones:

Say you have a service:

```
public class ServiceType
{
    public void DoSomething(string someData)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("Got this " + someData);
    }
}
```

Then in the hosting app (windows forms):

```
      IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();
      properties.Add("authorizedGroup", "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"); // or some other user account that runs the console app
      properties.Add("portName", "myApp" + Guid.NewGuid()); // if you rapidly restart your app then the pipe may still be there
      IpcServerChannel serverChannel = new IpcServerChannel(properties, null);
      ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);
      RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(ServiceType), "service", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

And then in the console app:

```
          var pipename = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("myApp")))

          IpcClientChannel clientChannel = new IpcClientChannel();
          ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, true);
          var s = (ServiceType)Activator.GetObject(typeof (ServiceType), "ipc://" + pipename.Replace(@"\\.\pipe\", string.Empty) + "/service");
          s.DoSomething("data");
          ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(clientChannel);
```

Of course you have to share the library for the ServiceType.